# Pandas - Count unique values in column A that satisfy condition in column B grouped by column C

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, unique, pandas-groupby

I have a fake dataset presenting a list of areas. These areas contain members and each member has a value.

I would like to count for each area, the number of unique members whose value satisfies a condition. I managed to deal with the issue but I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to do so in Pandas.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
# Building the fake dataset
dummy_dict = {
    "area": ["A","A", "A","A","B","B"],
    "member" : ["O1","O2","O2","O3","O1","O1"],
    "value" : [90, 200, 200, 150, 120, 120]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dummy_dict)
# Counting the number of unique members that satisfy the condition by zone 
value_cutoff = 100
df["nb_unique_members"] = df.groupby("area")["member"].transform("nunique")
df.loc[df["value"]>=value_cutoff,"tmp"] = df.loc[df["value"]>=value_cutoff].groupby("area")["member"].transform("nunique")
df["nb_unique_members_above_cutoff"] = df.groupby("area")["tmp"].transform("mean")
df.head()
```

Is there a better way to do so in Pandas ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your solution. only thing is the line `df.loc[df["value"]>=value_cutoff,"tmp"] = df.loc[df["value"]>=value_cutoff].groupby("area")["member"].transform("nunique")` can be simplified to `df["tmp"] = df.loc[df["value"]>=value_cutoff].groupby("area")["member"].transform("nunique")` - pandas should handle the indexes

Comment: Thank you, it's indeed less cumbersome :)!